# How to disappear images on a map view?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have created a map view application and overlay some images on the map view. While clicking a button, all the images should disappear. How to do this?..Please help

Comment: Refer this http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html..you can customize it..

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
listOfOverlays.clear();
mapView.invalidate();
```